# Android 9.0 creating a socket out on main thread cause android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, network-programming, udp

I encountered this error often lately... and it's something that started to happen only on **Android 9.0**.
This method just create the `DatagramSocket` for the connection I'm going to use (on separate `AsyncTask`)

```
private boolean initLink() {
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "initLink()");

    try {
        platformIPAddr = InetAddress.getByName(platformIPAddrStr);
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If the creation of the socket fails for some error (i.e. corrupted value on `platformIPAddrStr`)  the exception thrown by the system is:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

While I would/should expect `UnknownHostException` or `SecurityException`.

```
class SendCommandTask extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        try {
            sendCommands();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And if you are wondering it if `InitLink()` failed `SendCommands()` will not use network resources.

Comment: Show your `AsyncTask`. Also, it seems that the problem is originating from `InetAddress.getByName()` because if you go to docs, this method will throw `UnknownHostException ` or `SecurityException`. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress#getByName(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is quite old and will be thrown when you attempt to perform any networking on the main thread and if your targetSDK is Honeycomb or newer (SDK 11).

You should create your socket asynchronously, since the socket creation can also take some time.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Until Android 9.0 I never encountered such exception .. probably they enforced this check.